# How to fix coordinates doubling up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pygame, tuples

I'm currently making Snake in Pygame. My idea to make ir grow was that I would make a list of all his positions, an whenever he eats an apple, I would append another pygame.Surface and blit it on the coordinates behind the last position. I encountered a weird bug, that makes the snake go twice as fast as before. Can you help me? 
This is my code:

```
import pygame, math, random

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,640))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')

score = 0

x, y = 320,320
dx,dy = 32,32
running = True
dirUp, dirDown = False, False
dirLeft, dirRight = False, True
body = [(x,y)]
pos = []


squares = []
for i in range(640):
    if i % 32 == 0:
        squares.append(i)
food = pygame.image.load('fruit.png')
foodx,foody = random.choice(squares), random.choice(squares)

def isCollision(obsX, obsY, x, y):
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(obsX - x, 2) + math.pow(obsY - y, 2)) <= 0

def show_text():
    score_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',32)
    score_text = score_font.render('Score: {}'.format(score), True, (255,255,255))
    screen.blit(score_text, (0,0))

def remove_duplicates(listy):
    new_listy = []
    for item in listy:
        if item not in new_listy:
            new_listy.append(item)
    return new_listy

def move():
    global x,y
    if dirUp:
        y -= dy
    elif dirDown:
        y += dy
    elif dirRight:
        x += dx
    elif dirLeft:
        x -= dx

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    clock.tick(10)
    screen.fill((0,128,0))

    body[0] = (x,y)

    snakeImg = [pygame.image.load('snakeblock.png') for i in range(len(body))]

    if x > 608 or x < 0:
        running = False
    elif y > 608 or y < 0:
        running = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                dirUp = True
                dirLeft = dirDown = dirRight = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dirDown = True
                dirUp = dirLeft = dirRight = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dirRight = True
                dirUp = dirDown = dirLeft = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                dirLeft = True
                dirUp = dirDown = dirRight = False

    for i in range(len(body)):
        if isCollision(foodx,foody,body[i][0],body[i][1]):
            foodx, foody = random.choice(squares), random.choice(squares)
            score += 1
            body.insert(0,pos[-2])

        move()

        pos.append((x,y))
        screen.blit(food, (foodx, foody))
        screen.blit(snakeImg[i], (body[i][0], body[i][1]))
    pos = remove_duplicates(pos)
    show_text()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: "**I encountered a weird bug, that makes the snake go twice as fast as before**". What do you mean "before"?  What code did you change that resulted in the snake moving twice as fast?

Comment: Firstly, snake goes normally 32 per one iteration. When I eat an apple it goes twice as fast.

Comment: In your for loop inside your game loop you are calling `move()` on the first snake block for every snake body block. That means you are putting all your moves on your first block.

Comment: I know that. Usually instead of x and y would be body[i] = (body[i][0], body[i][1])

Comment: There are still problems with your code if you are moving each block. But, your question was "I encountered a weird bug, that makes the snake go twice as fast as before". This is because you are moving the block 3 times if there are 3 blocks. Which means the snake is going 3 times as fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other problems that you will encounter with your code like not testing for edge collision and snake block collision. But here is a starting point.

Your problem was you were moving your beginning block multiple times for each loop whenever you you had more than one block.

Here is the full code with comments.

```
import pygame, math, random

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,640))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')

score = 0

x, y = 320,320
dx,dy = 32,32
running = True
dirUp, dirDown = False, False
dirLeft, dirRight = False, True
body = [(x,y)]
pos = []


squares = []
for i in range(640):
    if i % 32 == 0:
        squares.append(i)
food = pygame.image.load('fruit.png')
food = pygame.transform.scale(food, (32,32))
foodx,foody = random.choice(squares), random.choice(squares)

def isCollision(obsX, obsY, x, y):
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(obsX - x, 2) + math.pow(obsY - y, 2)) <= 0

def show_text():
    score_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',32)
    score_text = score_font.render('Score: {}'.format(score), True, (255,255,255))
    screen.blit(score_text, (0,0))

def move(x, y):
    # I changed this function to take arguments and return
    # values rather than set globals which is generally bad practice
    if dirUp:
        y -= dy
    elif dirDown:
        y += dy
    elif dirRight:
        x += dx
    elif dirLeft:
        x -= dx

    return x, y

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    clock.tick(10)
    screen.fill((0,128,0))

    snakeImg = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('snakeblock.png'), (32,32)) for i in range(len(body))]

    if x > 608 or x < 0:
        running = False
    elif y > 608 or y < 0:
        running = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                dirUp = True
                dirLeft = dirDown = dirRight = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dirDown = True
                dirUp = dirLeft = dirRight = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dirRight = True
                dirUp = dirDown = dirLeft = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                dirLeft = True
                dirUp = dirDown = dirRight = False

    # this for loop is reversed because you only need to move your first block
    # the rest of the blocks can just follow the pattern of the previously 
    # placed blocks
    for i in reversed(range(len(body))):
        if isCollision(foodx,foody,body[i][0],body[i][1]):
            foodx, foody = random.choice(squares), random.choice(squares)
            score += 1
            body.insert(0, move(body[i][0], body[i][1]))
        elif i == 0:
            # Here you only move your first block or element
            body[i] = move(body[i][0], body[i][1])
        else:
            # otherwise you can just place the current element
            # at the position of the previous element
            body[i] = body[i - 1]

        screen.blit(food, (foodx, foody))
        screen.blit(snakeImg[i], (body[i][0], body[i][1]))

    show_text()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks! I had planned these problems' solutions in an another version of the code actually.

Answer (score 1):

For others to know how to make a snake crash into the wall and himself:

```
if body[0][0] > 608 or body[0][0] < 0:
        running = False
    elif body[0][1] > 608 or body[0][1] < 0:
        running = False
[...]

for i in range(len(body)):
        if body[0] in body[1:]:
            running = False
```